# zsh set verbose inside a function

Tags: zsh

```
# test1.sh
set -v
whoami

# test2.sh
myf () {
  set -v
  whoami
}
myf
```

It's unclear to me why `test2.sh` doesn't echo the command. I was expecting both scripts print:

```
whoami
<username>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`set -v` echoes lines as they are *read*. However, nothing is read when you execute `myf`; `test2.sh` has already been completely read by the time you call `myf`.